# microSD card suddenly inaccessible

Tags: sdhc

I have a microSd card with an adapter and suddenly it was inaccesible in my computer...
I would like to recover the data and the micro sd card :(
the output of dmesg command:

[ 3431.211177] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card

[ 3441.240046] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.

[ 3441.240054] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========

[ 3441.240062] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00000400

[ 3441.240069] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000

[ 3441.240076] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000

[ 3441.240083] sdhci: Present:  0x01f70001 | Host ctl: 0x00000001

[ 3441.240089] sdhci: Power:    0x00000000 | Blk gap:  0x00000000

[ 3441.240096] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000000

[ 3441.240102] sdhci: Timeout:  0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000

[ 3441.240109] sdhci: Int enab: 0x00ff00c3 | Sig enab: 0x00ff00c3

[ 3441.240116] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000

[ 3441.240122] sdhci: Caps:     0x01e032b2 | Caps_1:   0x00000000

[ 3441.240129] sdhci: Cmd:      0x00000102 | Max curr: 0x00000040

[ 3441.240132] sdhci: ===========================================

[ 3443.311158] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card

[ 3453.320021] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.

[ 3453.320027] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========

[ 3453.320034] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00000400

[ 3453.320039] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000

[ 3453.320044] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000

[ 3453.320050] sdhci: Present:  0x01f70001 | Host ctl: 0x00000001

[ 3453.320055] sdhci: Power:    0x00000000 | Blk gap:  0x00000000

[ 3453.320060] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000000

[ 3453.320065] sdhci: Timeout:  0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000

[ 3453.320070] sdhci: Int enab: 0x00ff00c3 | Sig enab: 0x00ff00c3

[ 3453.320075] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000

[ 3453.320080] sdhci: Caps:     0x01e032b2 | Caps_1:   0x00000000

[ 3453.320085] sdhci: Cmd:      0x00000102 | Max curr: 0x00000040

[ 3453.320087] sdhci: ===========================================

[ 3455.381075] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card

[ 3465.400115] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.

[ 3465.400123] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========

[ 3465.400132] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00000400

[ 3465.400139] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000

[ 3465.400146] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000

[ 3465.400153] sdhci: Present:  0x01f70001 | Host ctl: 0x00000001

[ 3465.400160] sdhci: Power:    0x00000000 | Blk gap:  0x00000000

[ 3465.400167] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000000

[ 3465.400174] sdhci: Timeout:  0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000

[ 3465.400181] sdhci: Int enab: 0x00ff00c3 | Sig enab: 0x00ff00c3

[ 3465.400187] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000

[ 3465.400194] sdhci: Caps:     0x01e032b2 | Caps_1:   0x00000000

[ 3465.400201] sdhci: Cmd:      0x00000102 | Max curr: 0x00000040

[ 3465.400203] sdhci: ===========================================

[ 3467.471070] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card

[ 3477.480029] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.

[ 3477.480037] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc0)===========

[ 3477.480046] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00000400

[ 3477.480054] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00000000 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000

[ 3477.480061] sdhci: Argument: 0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000000

[ 3477.480067] sdhci: Present:  0x01f70001 | Host ctl: 0x00000001

[ 3477.480074] sdhci: Power:    0x00000000 | Blk gap:  0x00000000

[ 3477.480081] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000000

[ 3477.480087] sdhci: Timeout:  0x00000000 | Int stat: 0x00000000

[ 3477.480094] sdhci: Int enab: 0x00ff00c3 | Sig enab: 0x00ff00c3

[ 3477.480100] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000

[ 3477.480107] sdhci: Caps:     0x01e032b2 | Caps_1:   0x00000000

[ 3477.480114] sdhci: Cmd:      0x00000102 | Max curr: 0x00000040

[ 3477.480116] sdhci: ===========================================

Thank you!

Comment: You need much more detail, like OS (I could guess) and what you where doing and what you have done. Did you pull and reseat the card? have you rebooted?

Comment: have you tried a different card in the socket?